# How do I keep a constant websocket connect in the background of firefox addon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, websocket, firefox-addon

I am currently try to migrate a chrome extension to firefox

I try to read the starter guide but find nothing like background.js in chrome

do I simply connect and maintain the socket in main.js? what is the life cycle of main.js, when will it be called can when will it be destroyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main.js` and other modules (under `lib/`) are indeed similar to `background.js` of chrome extensions.

`main.js` will be run when the add-on is started (after installation, or when the browser is started) and stays around until the add-on is shutdown (browser shutdown, user disables or uninstalls the add-on).

However, `main.js` does not have access to the HTML5 (DOM) APIs, as there is no underlying web-page. The easiest way to solve this is using [`page-worker`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-worker.html) with a local (`data/`) html page which does the actual websocket connection and use regular message passing between the worker and `main.js` or whatever other modules and/or content scripts you got.